# Scheduling a controller method by Windows task scheduller

Tags: php, codeigniter, taskmanager

I'm following this tutorial (http://amitdhamu.com/blog/automating-php-using-task-scheduler/) to schedule a task in PHP Codeignitre, however in step 1 of the mentioned tutorial I dont know how I can pass the controller method instead of a whole php file?! Could you please help me in this regard?

Also I need to provide the option of scheduling for the admin of my web application as well in a way that they can change the scheduleer; is there any way that I can pass the task manager options with PHP?

Please if my question is not clear, please let me know which part you need more clarification

PS: I have a windows server!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute CodeIgniter code from schedule, replace the call, in .bat:

from:

```
php C:\Apache\htdocs\automatic.php
```

to:

```
php C:\Apache\htdocs\index.php myController <myMethod> <arg1> <arg2>
```

sample:

```
php C:\Apache\htdocs\index.php users update
```

Comment: how can AUTH_USER be provided in such scenario?

Comment: you can create a not public path to expose without requirement of auth_user. ex: /localFunctions/myProcess.php. Internally the user will be set with a default user and call the inner methods

Comment: How can I do that?