# Scheduling PHP CodeIgniter or any PHP applications

Tags: php, codeigniter, windows-task-scheduler

I'm trying to schedule my Controller Method in PHP CodeIgniter; I mean I need to call a controller method on specified times!My server is a Windows Server!

So far I followed the following article (http://amitdhamu.com/blog/automating-php-using-task-scheduler/) which schedules a PHP file (calls whole of the PHP File, but I need to call just a controller method!); then I researched and someone at "[Scheduling a controller method by Windows task scheduller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479494/scheduling-a-controller-method-by-windows-task-scheduller)" said I can do it by:

```
php C:\Apache\htdocs\index.php myController <myMethod> <arg1> <arg2>
```

sample:

```
php C:\Apache\htdocs\index.php users update
```

I guess he meant something like :

```
php C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\application\controllers\site.php test
```

Which test method is inside my "site" controller! But this one did not work either!

Could you please how I use schedulig to call a controller method on specified times for a Windows Server?

Thanks

Comment: You don't call controllers directly, all requests even CLI requests should go through index.php, so for your case, index.php controller method arg1 arg2 ..etc

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience doing this, but Googling I managed to pull this together:

```
schtasks /create /tn "Test Cron Job" /tr "C:\PHP5\php.exe -f C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\application\controllers\site.php" /sc hourly
```

This will run hourly. I don't think you can specify a specific method, though you can add specific command line arguments.

Sources: http://php.net/manual/en/install.windows.commandline.php and http://drupal.org/node/31506

Comment: How if I put my controlller method in a seperate file in another controller class and call it in its constructor?

Comment: Yup, putting in separate file might work. You can also use command line arguments (check PHP.net link) to run a specific method.

Comment: Thanks man! But the same thing can be done by Windows task manager! I was looking for the right syntax that someone said here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479494/scheduling-a-controller-method-by-windows-task-scheduller

Comment: I think that poster is wrong in thinking it is possible to supply a method. But this command is supposed to create a task in the task manager, but instead of using a GUI you run this command.

Answer (score 0):

You can download curl(http://curl.haxx.se/) command line util and write a bat file to call your url where the controller method is executed then schedule the bat file in windows.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html

This is one of the be easiest way to achieve this.

Comment: Is that for Windows Server?